# Add php user input controller to wordpress customizer

Tags: wordpress, custom-controls, user-input, sanitization

Trying to customize the Wordpress Theme Customizer to allow users to input either a shortcode or a custom php string. Currently, I have many user input fields for text input, but I can't figure out how to sanitize the text correctly to allow for php.

Any suggestions on where to start?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you user5552351 for your response.
After looking at the codex you referenced in your comment, I realized I was way over thinking the solution.

Turns out all I needed was to give the user a text input that allows for basic brackets [] and apostrophes '' while inside a do_shortcode function.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode(get_theme_mod( 'THEME_MOD_ID', 'THEME_MOD_DEFAULT_VALUE' ));?>
```

where THEME_MOD_ID is the identifier for the Theme Customizer Control. So Basically there's a section in my theme customizer called 'Contact' that holds a text input setting/control called 'custom_contact_form', where a user can input a shortcode (ex: [simple_contact_form] ) and it will replace everything between do_shortcode( + ). So my code might look something like this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode(get_theme_mod( 'custom_contact_form', '' ));?>
```